# Scale specific component using sketchup ruby

Tags: ruby, components, selection, scale, sketchup

I'm extremely new to Sketchup Ruby.  If I have a .txt file containing a series of scale factors (1.2, 3.0, 12.1, etc...), is it possible to use ruby to:

1. Load the matrix from the .txt file
2. Select the component in the model based on its name (component 1, or something)
3. Apply the scale factor from the matrix using the scale tool
4. Move on to the next component and apply the next scale factor

Please help, I've been watching videos/ reading guides and I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: All of this is possible, but short of actually writing the whole script for you, what do you have so far?

Comment: @thomthom , I currently have the selection and what I thought would do the scaling.  So, I have 11 components, numbered 1-11.  For the first one:

`Sketchup.active_model.selection.add( Sketchup.active_model.definitions['1'].instances )
t = Geom::Transformation.scaling 1.5
Sketchup.active_model.selection.remove( Sketchup.active_model.definitions['1'].instances )`

Repeating this for each component.  However, I don't know how to load/ reference a matrix, at least in this environment, or why my scaling line of code isn't actually working.